# Obiee How to bring metrics in rows in report?

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

I want to build an OBIEE report related to support where I can bring the columns to rows and have its value beside it. Like,

```
                Previous Year Current Year
```

No. of open cases     123                   345

Attached is image for reference. [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1YVR.png)

Regards,
Harshita.

Comment: Harshita did you give up or did the response helped?

Comment: posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036958/how-to-achieve-the-below-goal-in-obiee-dashboard/19056024#19056024

Answer (score 0):

Use the pivot table view and pull the measures into the rows section. Done.